# IS it OK to use BIT as part of primary key?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of articles that may be published or still in draft, there may be around a 70/30 published/draft ratio. The most common search of the table will be for published articles. When executing this search, I've been lead to believe it would be faster to have the draft status as a part of the table and PK:

```
CREATE TABLE article(
id VARCHAR(6),
draft BIT(1),
content TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY(draft, id)
)
```

..than to normalise it and have a separate table that holds article.id numbers to indicate that they are still in draft.

- Am I wrong about the speed hit of looking in an extra, normalised, table?
- Is there any problem using `BIT` as part of a PK with up to date versions of MySQL?

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY(draft, id)` means that you can have two articles with the same `id` (one draft and one published) - is that what you want?

Comment: "The most common search of the table will be for published articles" , if we can see the SQL you run to do that, it will be a lot easier to provide relevant help for you. If you're looking up rows based on `id` only, your current primary key is useless (and also a bit dangerous, as your current primary key allows duplicated `id` values). If you're searching through `content` as well, would need other indexes, etc.

Comment: That's OK for now, yes. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> When executing this search, I've been lead to believe it would be
>   faster to have the draft status as a part of the table and PK

Forget for a moment about speed, because that's not most important consideration here. Primary purpose of primary key (pun intended) is to establish column subset that *uniquely identifies* whole row. So, questions you should be asking are:

- Is this `draft` bit part of `article` identity? Or does `id` alone identify `article`?
- Can two articles with the same `id` but different `draft` status coexist at the same time?

Depending on that, you should consider whether to include `draft` bit in primary key.

If you are concerned about performance, you could consider creating additional index.